# How do I make these charts?

Tags: charts

I am looking to create stock charts similar to;

http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=SPY&ty=c&ta=0&p=d

I have been looking a:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/ohlc

which I think is good but does anyone know how I can create something similar as the charts at Finviz? Any developer or programmer that you can recomend?

Thanks

Samuelsson

Answer (score -1):

I spent a considerable amount of time looking at charting controls for our WPF application. It's a manufacturing application containing roughly 30 charts. The best control I found was Visifire (www.visifire.com). I've been using it for roughly 6-9 months and am very pleased with it. And it supports stock charts like you've described.

Comment: visifire is no longer in service.